# Custom group not visible in user.aspx page?

Tags: 2013, site-collection, security

In the `Site Settings` area, what is the difference between:

- `People and groups`
- `Site permissions`

I have created some custom groups from the page:

```
/_layouts/15/groups.aspx
```

and they are not showing on the page:

```
/_layouts/15/user.aspx
```

Below is a screenshot of the relevant links in the `Site Settings` area:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"People and groups" page shows all groups and groups members, "Site permissions" from the other side shows you only those users and groups, which has permissions assigned on this particular site.

Since you created a group, but didn't assign any permissions yet, the group will not be under "Site permissions"

Comment: Hi i added a custom permission level to  a group , while creating this group, but i can not view in site permissions page

Comment: Click on "Check Permissions", type in the group name and see, if your group has permissions.

Comment: yes i did not added permission level to this group when i check permissions thanks kai

Comment: Why Translation Managers,Style Resource Readers,Quick Deploy Users groups not in users.aspx page even they have permission level?

Comment: "Translation Managers" should be on the `users.aspx`, because the group has `Restricted Interfaces for Translation` permission level. Also please note, that this page showing only permissions given to user or group directly **on the site level**. For example `Quick Deploy Users` has `Contribute` at the list level (`Quick Deploy Items ` list). That's why you can't see it. `Style Resources Readers` is system group with Limited Access permission, that's why it also doesn't show.

Comment: When you say `'People and groups' page shows all groups and groups members` - are these groups that have been manually added to the particular site?  Or are they inherited from elsewhere?  I see about 50 groups that I didn't create.  When I click on them, they don't display a list of users, they display things like:  `Account:  c:0t.c|tenant|*******-*****-*****-*****-*******`, `Name:   Some_Group_Name` and `Email:  some_email@mydomain.com`.  I am in SharePoint Online and the site is running an app on it, so maybe an app has added all the groups that it references in its `Person` type fields?

Answer (score 0):

**People and groups**:Specify users and user group  who have access to this site and any sub site which inherits permission

**Site permissions**: Define capability of each user and or user group can perform on this site and sub site inheriting from